# file_get_contents equivalent for setting cookies

Tags: php, curl, file-get-contents

I'm trying to make a request to a website which requires login but the server doesn't support the https protocol so I can't use curl.

The original code that I have looks like this:

```
    $ch = curl_init();

    $options = array(
        CURLOPT_URL => $url,
        CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => false,
        CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => 1,
        CURLOPT_USERAGENT => 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:15.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/15.0',
        CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR => dirname(__FILE__) . '\cookies.txt',
        CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE => dirname(__FILE__) . '\cookies.txt',
        CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => 1
    )

    curl_setopt_array($ch, $options);

    $page = curl_exec ($ch);
```

And I came up with the following when using file_get_contents:

```
    $cookies = file_get_contents(dirname(__FILE__) . '\cookies.txt');

    $primary_context_options = array(
        "http" => array(
            "method" => "GET",
            "follow_location" => true,
            "header" => "Cookie: " . $cookies .  "\r\n" . 
            "User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:15.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/15.0\r\n"
        ),
        "ssl" => array(
            "verify_peer" => false,
        )
    );

    $primary_context = stream_context_create($primary_context_options);
    $page = file_get_contents($url, false, $primary_context);
```

The first request is returning fine, but I'm not sure if I'm setting the cookie correctly.
The only problem is with the second request in which I login using the credentials:

```
        $login_context_options = array(
            "http" => array(
                "method" => "POST",
                "header" => "Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n"
                    . "Content-Length: " . strlen($post) . "\r\n"
                    . "Referer: " . $url  . "\r\n", 
                "content: " . $post
            )
        );



        $login_context = stream_context_create($login_context_options);
        $login = file_get_contents($login_url, false, $login_context);
```

It always returns:

```
"file_get_contents($url_encoded_login_url_of_website) failed to open stream: HTTP request failed!"
```

I can login fine with the given url using curl so I don't know what I am missing here.

If it helps, here's the original code that uses curl for the login:

```
        $additional_options = array(
            CURLOPT_URL => $login_url, 
            CURLOPT_REFERER => $url,
            CURLOPT_POST => 1,
            CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => $post
        );

        curl_setopt_array($ch, $additional_options);
        curl_exec($ch);
```

Any ideas what mistakes could I have made with the file_get_contents version? Thanks in advance!

Comment: `cURL` doesn't operate only via https, so if that was only one problem with it, go back to `cURL`.

Comment: do you mean replacing all the https url with just http? I tried that and it works with the server with https enabled but not on the server without https enabled

Comment: No, if remote website uses http, then use http, if https then https. Don't replace anything, just use as it is.